# Import and extract data from multiple APIs in R

Tags: r, api, url

I imported 2 APIs (Application Programming Interfaces) into R:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)

a0 <- fromJSON("https://hello.com/users/0/bets") 
a1 <- fromJSON("https://hello.com/users/1/bets")
```

I get a data frame from each API:

```
a0 <- df0
a1 <- df1
```

Using `bind_rows` from `dplyr` library, I merged the two data frames into a single one (I can also use `rbind.data.frame`):

```
a <- bind_rows(a1, a2)
```

I have 500 APIs in total, ranging from `https://hello.com/users/0/bets` to `https://hello.com/users/499/bets`, so I want to do what I've done above for all of them.

I can't seem to find a solution to this, so can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

- Create an empty list to store each data.frame you plan to grab
- Loop over the URLs to grab the dataframes, storing each as a list element
- Then `do.call(rbind)` all the dataframes together.

.

```
result_list <- vector(mode="list", length=500)
for(bet in 0:499) {
    this_url <- paste0("https://hello.com/users/", bet, "/bets")
    result_list[[bet]] <- fromJSON(this_url)
}
result <- do.call(rbind, result_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a `map` function from `purrr`/`tidyverse`, you can do it in one line. `map_dfr` is a function that basically calls `map` to apply some function over a list (in this case, `fromJSON`), then calls `reduce` to apply `bind_rows` to all elements in the list, returning a single data frame.

If your URLs are, in fact, as simple as this with just an integer in them, you can `map` over `1:500`, make a URL with that integer, then call `fromJSON`. I'm using `stringr::str_glue` to make the URLs, but if you have the actual ones in a different format, you can adjust.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

map_dfr(1:500, ~fromJSON(str_glue("https://hello.com/users/{.}/bets")))
```